# A system of polynomial equations $f_i = x^{m_i} - x^{n_i} -1$, $m_i>n_i>0$, for $i = 1,2$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, systems-of-equations

Consider the following polynomials
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
f_1(x) = x^{m_1} - x^{n_1} - 1, \ &m_1>n_1>0 \\
f_2(x) = x^{m_2} - x^{n_2} - 1, \ &m_2>n_2>0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
**Problem:** For which values of $m_1,n_1,m_2,n_2$ the system of polynomial equations $f_1 = f_2 =0$ has a real solution $x_0>1$?

**Some considerations:**

Observe that $f_i(1) = -1$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f_i(x) = +\infty$; hence, by the intermediate value theorem, $f_i$ has a real solution greater than unity. Additionally $f_i'(x) = m_ix^{m_i-1} - n_ix^{n_i-1} >0, \ \forall x>1$, from which these polynomials are strictly increasing. Thus such a root is unique.

So the problem may be reformulated as whether the unique real roots greater than unity of $f_1$ and $f_2$ coincide.

An example of solution is given by $m_1 = 5$, $n_1 = 4$, $m_2 = 3$, $n_2 = 1$, for which the polynomials $f_1$ and $f_2$ share the root $\lambda =  \frac{\sqrt[3]{9-\sqrt{69}}+\sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{69}}}{\sqrt[3]{2}3^{2/3}} \approx 1.325$. This example can be extended to a family of solutions given by $m_1 = 5k$, $n_1 = 4k$, $m_2 = 3k$, $n_2 = k$, for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, whose roots are $\lambda^{1/k}$, and I verified numerically that these are the only solutions for polynomials with degree up to 100.

I would like to know if the above family of solutions is actually the only solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance for any help or insight about this problem.

Comment: Interesting question, though it doesn't look easy even without the additional constraint of the common root to be real and $\,\gt 1\,$. See (the unanswered) [Resultant of two special trinomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269891/resultant-of-two-special-trinomials) on MO, and the references in the comments to OEIS [A001350](https://oeis.org/A001350) and [A001945](http://oeis.org/A001945). The latter suggests that yours is the only solution for $\,f_2(x)=x^3-x-1\,$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @dxiv. I was not aware of this (more general) question on MO. Note however that our additional constraint of the common root to be real and $>1$ may be used to show some nice properties. For example, if we assume WLOG that $m_1 > m_2$, and supposing that $f_1$ and $f_2$ have a common root, then we must have $m_2-n_2 > m_1-n_1$. This shows that the above number $\lambda$ is not a root of a polynomial with degree higher than 5. With this bound we can show that this solution is indeed unique for $f_2(x) = x^3 - x -1$, as you suggested.

Comment: Right, you can draw additional conclusions in your case. For example $\,f_i(x)\,$ has one unique positive real root by Descartes' rule of signs, and that root is $\,\gt 1\,$ as you noted. If $\,m_1 \gt m_2\,$ then you can also derive that $\,n_1 \gt n_2\,$, and therefore $\,2(n_1-n_2) \gt m_1 - m_2\,$, which further narrows down the search space. However, I don't see a solution for the general case offhand.

Comment: Right. It seems that these additional properties are not helping for the very general case. I also tried to reformulate the problem in different ways. For example considering the product $g = f_1f_2$. Solution for the system $f_1=f_2=0$ is equivalent to uniqueness of a positive root for $g$; in this case, the root has multiplicity 2 and $g$ shall be nonnegative in the positive axis. On the other hand, when the system has no solution, $g$ will have two positive roots, and it assumes negative values in between them.  But, as expected, I had no success with these new attempts.

Comment: Since it's been a couple of days with no answers here, I would consider mabye posting the question on MO, with a reference to this one on MSE.